# Disable double sided faces in Blender 3D View

Tags: 3d-view, normals

For Debugging purposes in Animations I would like to disable Blenders default both sided rendering of faces in the 3D view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Properties panel <kbd>N</kbd> find section "Shading" -> "Backface culling":

[image]